# Multilevel sidebar menu using JS/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have a responsive sidebar navigation (as part of making the website responsive) for a multilevel menu of depth 3. The html markup is as below,

```
<nav>
    <div data-level="1">
        <ul>
            <li class="main-menu">
                Level1
                <div data-level="2">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="submodule">
                            example1.1
                            <div data-level="3">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>example1.1.1</li>
                                    <li>example1.1.2</li>
                                    <li>example1.1.3</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="submodule">
                            example1.2
                            <div data-level="2">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>example1.2.1</li>
                                    <li>example1.2.2</li>
                                    <li>example1.2.3</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="submodule">
                            example1.3
                            <div data-level="2">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>example1.3.1</li>
                                    <li>example1.3.2</li>
                                    <li>example1.3.3</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                Level2
                <div data-level="2">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            example2.1
                            <div data-level="3">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>example2.1.2</li>
                                    <li>example2.1.3</li>
                                    <li>example2.1.4</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            example2.2
                            <div data-level="2">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>example2.2.1</li>
                                    <li>example2.2.2</li>
                                    <li>example2.2.3</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            example2.3
                            <div data-level="2">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>example2.3.1</li>
                                    <li>example2.3.2</li>
                                    <li>example2.3.4</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>           
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

At first menu shows only the top level,

Level1
Level2

When Level1 is clicked menu should show,

Back to Main Menu
example 1.1
example 1.2

When example1.1 is clicked,

Back to sublevel
example1.1.1
example1.1.2
example1.1.3

Each of back button takes to the menu before.

How to do the navigation using JS/jQuery?

Comment: Show us what you have tried ! **javascript**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was necessary to adjust your navigation a little bit - the navigation for Level 2 was missing the `submodule` class. In addition you could consider to adjust your usage of `<div data-level="3">` as you only use it for the 2nd and 3rd sublevel navigation while the 1st sublevel is in a `<div data-level="2">`. The following navigation fulfills your requirements while it is not complete - you can adjust it so a visible sublevel navigation gets toggled when the main navigation gets clicked. I already took care about the issue to only have one main navigation and submodule navigation visible at the same time.

```js
$(".main-menu").on("click", function() {
   if ($(".main-menu").not(this).find(".submodule").is(":visible")) {
      $(".main-menu").not(this).find(" > div[data-level='2'], .submodule").hide();
  }
   $(this).find(" > div[data-level='2'], .submodule").toggle();
});
$(".submodule").on("click", function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(".submodule").not(this).each(function() {
      if ($(this).find(" > div[data-level='3'], > div[data-level='2']").is(":visible")) {
         $(this).find(" > div[data-level='3'], > div[data-level='2']").hide();
      }
   });
   $(this).find(" > div[data-level='3'], > div[data-level='2']").toggle();
});
$(".submodule.back").on("click", function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).closest(".main-menu").find(" > div[data-level='2'], .submodule").hide();;
});

$(".back").not(".submodule").on("click", function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).closest(".submodule").find(" > div[data-level='3'], > div[data-level='2']").hide();
});
```

```css
div[data-level ="2"]{
  display:none;
}
div[data-level ="3"]{
  display:none;
}
.submodule {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div data-level="1">
    <ul>
      <li class="main-menu">
        Level1
        <div data-level="2">
          <ul>
            <li class="submodule back">
              Back to main menu
              </li>
            <li class="submodule">
              example1.1
              <div data-level="3">
                <ul>
                  <li class="back">Back to sublevel</li>
                  <li>example1.1.1</li>
                  <li>example1.1.2</li>
                  <li>example1.1.3</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="submodule">
              example1.2
              <div data-level="2">
                <ul>
                <li class="back">Back to sublevel</li>
                  <li>example1.2.1</li>
                  <li>example1.2.2</li>
                  <li>example1.2.3</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="submodule">
              example1.3
              <div data-level="2">
                <ul>
                <li class="back">Back to sublevel</li>
                  <li>example1.3.1</li>
                  <li>example1.3.2</li>
                  <li>example1.3.3</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="main-menu">
        Level2
        <div data-level="2">
          <ul>
            <li class="submodule back">
              Back to main menu
              </li>
            <li class="submodule">
              example2.1
              <div data-level="3">
                <ul>
                  <li class="back">Back to sublevel</li>
                  <li>example2.1.2</li>
                  <li>example2.1.3</li>
                  <li>example2.1.4</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="submodule">
              example2.2
              <div data-level="2">
                <ul>
                  <li class="back">Back to sublevel</li>
                  <li>example2.2.1</li>
                  <li>example2.2.2</li>
                  <li>example2.2.3</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>           
            <li class="submodule">
              example2.3
              <div data-level="2">
                <ul>
                  <li class="back">Back to sublevel</li>
                  <li>example2.3.1</li>
                  <li>example2.3.2</li>
                  <li>example2.3.4</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```